# Hiding the tabpages tabs and the edge arround it

Tags: c#, colors, hide, tabcontrol

I need to hide the edge arround my tabcontrol.
I can hide the labels @ the top of the control with this:

```
   Maintab.Appearance = TabAppearance.FlatButtons; 
   Maintab.ItemSize = new Size(0, 1); 
   Maintab.SizeMode = TabSizeMode.Fixed;
```

But I still have a grey edge arround it. I need to give it a different color or let it dissapear. [image: The grey edge needs to be removed]

Comment: `TabPage` could be replaces with `Panel`, why do you use `TabControl`?

Comment: I need to switch between the tabpages automatically. I need to make an application for school TV. Sometimes it shows something on tab1 sometimes on tab2. It's easier to work with. If I use 4 different panels I need to get 1 to the front and the others to the back. If it's really to hard to get rid of the edge, I can use the panels. I was just curious if you can remove the edge.

Comment: Yep I tried, still shows the border.

Comment: No. Sinatr is right. You don't want to use a Tab, just just think you do. Use Panels or UserControls and Show one and hide all the others. No need to bring things to front.. Tabs are for users to select a Tab freely.